# Spring MVC Multi page form Data Handling in controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want some stateful bean or wizard functionality for multiple page form.

I have a page to capture data. We spited into multiple page (4- steps) for User Experience. Project is using Spring MVC (Controller) for web layer. I need to submit and validate data after each step. I also need to use data captured from first step in third step to give user choice. Data can not be persisted in DB/Session.

Can someone help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Spring Controllers are stateless and that is not its use. I recommend you use another tools like Spring Web Flow.

https://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/

Comment: It required new dependency and I am not allowed to do that. That is why I am looking to create something with Controllers :(